# Retrieve all objects that match value in array

Tags: node.js, mongoose

im trying to get all matching objects that match a certain value but its not working

this is my bd:

[image: [1]: https://imgur.com/a/1RfMIvd"]

My model.js

```
var professorSchema = new schema({ 
nome : {type: String},
email : {type: String},
url : {type: String}
})

var aulaSchema = new schema ({
tipo : {type: String},
data : {type: String},
})

var sumarioSchema = new schema({
disciplina : {type: String},
professor : {professorSchema},
aula :[aulaSchema]
})
```

and my controller.js

```
Sumarios.listAula = ()=>{
return Sumario.aggregate(
    // Start with a $match pipeline which can take advantage of an index and limit documents processed
    { $match : {
       "aula.tipo":"T"
    }},
    { $unwind : "$aula" },
    { $match : {
       "aula.tipo":"T"
    }}
  ).exec() 
}
```

This query that im trying to do in the controller is returning every data, not what i want.. Is it a problem with my model?

Comment: you can also do: `Sumario.find({"aula.tipo":"T"}).select({"aula.$":1}).exec()`

Comment: @saikatchakrabortty i tried that but it dont work either. And its nor really what i want because that will only return one element, i want all